# Glassfish can not consume SSL web service

Tags: ssl, glassfish, webservice-client

I have a simple Java app that consumes a web service. The web service uses a .p12 file as keystore:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "pkcs12");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "/certs/cert.p12");
```

I also have a .jsp file that calls the function in the .JAR:

```
<%@ page import="dk.jems.wsTest65.WSTest65" %>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Web service from NetBeans 6.5.1</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>Hello Web service</div>
    <% WSTest65.test(); %>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have deployed the app in Tomcat and it works fine (WSTest65.test consumes the web service and writes the result to stdout), but in GlassFish, I get the following error:

```
HTTP transport error: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

Any suggestions why this works in Tomcat and not in GlassFish?

Best regards
Stefan

Answer (score 2):

I once had a similar problem, that was caused by the Glassfish client certificates not beeing valid.

Glassfish seems to send its client SSL certificates to the server during connect. If the other server is configured to validate this certs, the connection is possibly not going to be established.

A solution for me was, to provide the call with an empty keystore, overwriting the keystore in the configuration directory. Perhaps you could do the same, but instead of using an empty keystore you could use your own p12 keystore.

I also think setting the System properties will not work in glassfish during runtime.

I attach some code, perhaps it might be helpful to you

```
@RequestScoped
public class WebserviceWrapper {

private Port createAndPingWebservice() {
    ....
    SSLContext sslCtx = SSL_CONTEXT_WITHOUT_CLIENT_CERTS;
    ctxt.put("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.https.client.SSLSocketFactory", sslCtx.getSocketFactory());
    ctxt.put("com.sun.xml.ws.transport.https.client.SSLSocketFactory", sslCtx.getSocketFactory());

    return port;
}

private static final SSLContext SSL_CONTEXT_WITHOUT_CLIENT_CERTS;

static {
    SSLContext sslCtx = null;
    try {
        sslCtx = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        TrustManager[] trustManagers = new TrustManager[]{
            new X509TrustManager() {
                @Override
                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return new X509Certificate[0];
                }

                @Override
                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                }

                @Override
                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                }
            }
        };

        KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");

        try (InputStream keyStoreIn = WebserviceWrapper.class.getResourceAsStream("emptyKeystore.jks")) {
            ks.load(keyStoreIn, "changeit".toCharArray());
        }
        kmf.init(ks, "changeit".toCharArray());

        sslCtx.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), trustManagers, null);

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyStoreException | IOException | CertificateException | UnrecoverableKeyException | KeyManagementException e) {
        Logger.getLogger(WebserviceWrapper.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
    }
    SSL_CONTEXT_WITHOUT_CLIENT_CERTS = sslCtx;
}

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the code, but I have tried that approach.
I believe you are correct about System properties in runtime, and I was told to try to set httpsOutboundKeyAlias which gave a completely different result:

    [com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl] [tid: _ThreadID=32 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(6)] [timeMillis: 1412840535990] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  WSSTUBE0025: Error in Verifying Security in the Inbound Message.
com.sun.xml.wss.XWSSecurityException: Security Requirements not met - No Security header in message

    WSSTUBE0025: Error in Verifying Security in the Inbound Message.